# Cloud Code Parse Limit 1000 overcome with Chaining?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have the following function below which I am using to determine a users rank in a scoreboard.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getUserGlobalRank", function(request, response) 
{
    var usernameString = request.params.username;
    var scoreAmount = request.params.score;

    var globalRankQuery = new Parse.Query("scoreDB");
        globalRankQuery.greaterThanOrEqualTo("score",scoreAmount);  
        globalRankQuery.descending("score");
        globalRankQuery.limit("1000");
        globalRankQuery.count(
        {
        success: function(count);
        {
            response.success(count);                
        },
```

.........

However this will not give an accurate response if there are more than 1000 entries that meet that criteria. I would like to chain together a set of .find methods that I can subsequently perform a .count on. Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this? If you could provide a code example that would be great!

Many thanks,
James

Comment: Also provide a reference of the service you are using, so maybe someone can help you.

Comment: it's called Parse. www.parse.com

Answer (score 5):

The following answer will work in Cloud Code as it keeps track of the count by using a function parameter in successive calls to getUserGlobalRank(). I have used this architecture in similar cases successfully.

As Gene Z. Ragan mentioned in his comment, the currently accepted answer will not work in Cloud Code because there is no 'window' object.

The reason that recursion has been offloaded to a regular Javascript function is because Parse has a very low recursion limit for Cloud Code functions (I have verified that >4 recursive calls to a Cloud Code function will result in an error). By implementing the recursion in a Javascript function, you can bypass Parse's recursive limit, and continue making recursive calls as long as the code executes in the permitted time (about 15 seconds).

```
Parse.Cloud.define('getUserGlobalRank', function(request, response) {
     getUserGlobalRank({'username':request.params.username, 'score':request.params.score}, {
        success: function(count) {
            response.success(count);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error(error);
        }
    }); 
});

function getUserGlobalRank(request, response) {

    var usernameString = request['username'];
    var scoreAmount = request['score'];
    var count = (request['count'])? request['count'] : 0;

    var globalRankQuery = new Parse.Query("scoreDB");
    globalRankQuery.greaterThanOrEqualTo("score", scoreAmount);  
    globalRankQuery.descending("score");
    globalRankQuery.limit(1000);
    globalRankQuery.skip(count);
    globalRankQuery.find({
        success: function(results) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                count = count + results.length;
                getUserGlobalRank({'count':count, 'username':usernameString, 'score':scoreAmount}, response);
            }
            else { // found count of users with higher ranks
                response.success(count);
            }
        },
        error: function(error) { // query error
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

My goal was to iterate through all users on Parse. Here's my answer based on keither04's answer that is based on Cam Tullos's answer =]

```
Parse.Cloud.job("checkUsers", function (request, response) 
{
    // {} - empty params for first iteration
    getAllUsers({}, {
        success: function (users) {
            // Do stuff with users
            response.success("Loaded " + users.length + " users");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
});

function getAllUsers (request, response) 
{
    var users = (request["users"]) ? request["users"] : [];
    var skip = users.length;
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    userQuery.limit(1000);
    userQuery.skip(skip);
    userQuery.find({
        success: function (results) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                var allUsers = users.concat(results);
                var params = {"users": allUsers};
                getAllUsers(params, response);
            } else {
                response.success(users);
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
}
```

P.S.: I'm curious if it's possible to do using promises.

Answer (score 3):

Parse.Query.count() is not affected by the Parse.com 1000 query limit.

So you will get a correct count returned no matter how many entries matched by the query.

eg:

```
var userQ = new Parse.Query('_User');
userQ.count({success:function(count){console.log(count)}});
> 1512

var userQ = new Parse.Query('_User');
userQ.limit(100);
userQ.count({success:function(count){console.log(count)}});
> 1512
```

Bonus points - `.limit()` takes a number as its parameter, not a string as in your code.
https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#limit

hth

Comment: Hi thanks, for this response. My code snippet isn't very clear I agree. The question was actually that the standard Parse query is limited by 1000. If we require more records than this. Let's say there are 1100 then we could do a count and then run two queries (the second with a skip of 1000). My questions is then how would you combine the two results into a single results object. Many thanks, James

Comment: That should be quite simple - you could use underscore JS's .union() to combine two or more results arrays. [http://underscorejs.org/#union]

Comment: Are you sure the limitation of 1000 doesn't apply for count? The docs say it does, but there has to be SOME way around this. Just wondering if you've run used count personally on more than 1000 objects.

Comment: That is not true @Meirion . In Parse, if the number of rows in a 'table' is larger than 1000, the result is either approximate, correct, or will yield in a timeout'. Check the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Beware when using count. For classes with over 1000 objects, count operations are limited by timeouts. They may routinely yield timeout errors or return results that are only approximately correct. Thus, it is preferable to architect your application to avoid this sort of count operation. I typically use the skip parameter like so:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('getUserGlobalRank', function(request, response) {
var output = [];
var usernameString = request.params.username;
var scoreAmount = request.params.score;
var skip = (request.params['skip']) ? request.params.skip : 0;

if (skip == 0 || !window['results']) { window['results'] = []; }

var qry = new Parse.Query('scoreDB');
qry.greaterThanOrEqualTo('score', scoreAmount);
qry.descending('score');
qry.limit(1000);
qry.skip(skip);
qry.find({
    success: function (results) {
        if (results.length > 0) { // got results..
            output = output.concat(results);

            // Call the function again
            var params = request.params;
            params['skip'] = results.length;
            request.params = params;
            Parse.Cloud.run('getUserGlobalRank', request, response);

        } else { // we're done here
            response.success(output);
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {

    }
});
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the limitation of 1000 exists for count? I know the docs say it does, but the person answering below says it doesn't apply. Just wondering if you've run into issues personally.

Comment: Yes, and the behavior is rather weird as well. You don't get any sort of indication that you're at the limit either.

Comment: There is no window object available in CloudCode.  How is this code properly working?

Comment: @RyanWaggoner link to official docs: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-counting-objects - `count()` is **not** limited but can be _inaccurate_ and can time out for large (>1000 objects) classes

Answer (score 0):

Reckon this should work as far as implementing promises. Also, pretty sure skip is only supported up to 10,000 unfortunately, but I've been wrong before. Full disclosure, I've not tested this code.

```
    Parse.Cloud.job("checkUsers", function(request, response) {
        // {} - empty params for first iteration
        getAllUsers({}).then(function(users) {
            // Do stuff with users
          response.success("Loaded " + users.length + " users");
        },
        function(error) {
            response.error(error);
        });

    });

    function getAllUsers(request) {
        //
      var users = (request["users"]) ? request["users"] : [];
      var skip = users.length;
      var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
      userQuery.limit(1000);
      userQuery.skip(skip);

      Parse.Promise.as().then(function() {
        //
        return userQuery.find().then(null, function(error) {
            //
            return Parse.Promise.error(error);

        });     

      }).then(function(userObjects) {
        //
        if (userObjects.length > 0) {
          var allUsers = users.concat(userObjects);
          var params = {"users": allUsers};
          getAllUsers(params);
        } else {
            //
          return Parse.Promise.resolve(allUsers);
        }       

      },
      function(error) {
        //
        return Parse.Promise.reject(error);
      });

    }
```