# How to query in loop to fetch all data from class

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform

I have a class with (currently) 1567 objects. They are urls,title and publication dates of article which I parse from RSS feeds of websites. The cloud job is periodic, so the objects keep on increasing. Although I check for uniqueness in beforesave, from time to time some duplicate items creep up, approximately 10% of objects are duplicate.

I have been trying to make a job to delete these duplicates and want to make a query logic which can get ALL the objects at once. The maximum limit of query is 1000. I referred to [this question on Parse Help](https://parse.com/questions/fetch-all-data-in-a-table-using-pfquery), and tried to convert it into JavaScript cloud code.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("DeleteDuplicate", function(request, status) {

var query = new Parse.Query(NewsArticle);
var allObjectArray= [];
var limit = 1000;
var skip = 0;
var repeat = true;
query.limit(limit);
query.skip(skip);
do{
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            allObjectArray.push(results.concat());
            if(results.length === limit){
                skip = skip+limit;
                query.skip(skip);
                repeat = true;
                console.log("true");
            }else{
                repeat = false;
                console.log("false");
            }
            console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            status.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
}while(repeat);
    status.success("final length "+allObjectArray.length);
});
```

The code fails with the Job Status of "**Could not connect to Cloud Code**". I think it goes to infinite loop and times out after 2-3 minutes. If anyone can help, that would be great.

EDIT: Can using `Promise` help?

---

EDIT 2: Been trying Promise now -

```
Parse.Cloud.job("jobFindAll", function(request, status) {

var query = new Parse.Query(NewsArticle);
var allObjectArray= [];
var limit = 1000;
var skip = 0;
var repeat = false;
query.limit(limit);
query.skip(skip);
var promiseList = [];

console.log("in job");
query.find().then(function(results) {
    console.log("results.length "+results.length);
    allObjectArray = results.slice();
    console.log("allObjectArray.length "+allObjectArray.length);
    if(results.length === limit){
        console.log("smaller");
        skip = skip+limit;
        do{
            console.log("first repeat = "+repeat);
            promiseList.push(functionFindAll(allObjectArray, limit, skip));
            console.log("promiseList - "+promiseList);
            repeat = promiseList[promiseList.length-1];
            console.log("looping repeat = "+repeat);
        }while(repeat);
        return Parse.Promise.when(promiseList);
    }else{
        console.log("longer");
    }
}).then(function(){
        console.log("in then");
        status.success("final length "+allObjectArray.length);
    }, function(error) {
        status.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
);
});

function functionFindAll(allObjectArray, limit, skip){
var returnPromiseList = [];
var query_new = new Parse.Query(NewsArticle);
query_new.limit(limit);
query_new.skip(skip);
query_new.find().then(function(results) {
    console.log("function results.length "+results.length);
    if(results.length === limit){
        skip = skip+limit;
        query.skip(skip);
        allObjectArray.push(results.concat());
        console.log("true in function");
        return Parse.Promise.as(true);
    }else{
        allObjectArray.push(results.concat());
        return Parse.Promise.as(false);
        console.log("false in function");
    }
},
function(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    return Parse.Promise.as("ERROR!");
}
);
console.log("below "+allObjectArray.length);
}
```

Now the code doesnt enter the query_new.find(). The log messages in the function doesnt appear,  directly the message "below...." appears.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following code will find all the items in the class, it does not use skip because parse.com has another freaking limit call `"unable to skip more than 10000 items"`. it skip using the objectId.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("findAll", function(request, status) {
  var result = [];

  var processCallback = function(res) {
    result = result.concat(res);
    if (res.length === 1000) {
      process(res[res.length-1].id);
      return;
    }

    // do something about the result, result is all the object you needed.
    status.success("final length " + result.length);
  }
  var process = function(skip) {

    var query = new Parse.Query("NewsArticle");

    if (skip) {
      console.log("in if");
      query.greaterThan("objectId", skip);
    }
    query.limit(1000);
    query.ascending("objectId");
    query.find().then(function querySuccess(res) {
      processCallback(res);
    }, function queryFailed(reason) {
      status.error("query unsuccessful, length of result " + result.length + ", error:" + error.code + " " + error.message);
    });
  }
  process(false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. Check this out http://pastebin.com/9Gw1UC4N . I am getting `success/error was not called` error.

Comment: you have a missing `}` for the block if (skip). Where is NewsArticle coming from? Why it is not in quotes?

Comment: The NewsArticle is an instance which I have declared at top because it is used by some other jobs too (which work fine). `var NewsArticle = Parse.Object.extend("newsArticle");` I think it is now quering correct numbers but not adding to results array. The logs are below in this file http://pastebin.com/2GvJvTx3 . Would slice() help?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the assignment, updated. `result = result.concat(res);`

Comment: Yes I was just about to comment this. Thanks, its now working.

Comment: Last question, can I directly call this from another job to return the `results` array?

Comment: No I don't think so. parse has got alot of annoying limit. It is easy to start but once you get to seriously use it, it started get frustrating. You can try to write a cloud function to process the result, calling it from this job with httprequest. or do the processing in this job and "httprequest save result as csv/json in cloud file".

Answer (score 1):

All JS calls in Parse are asynchronous, so your function is spawning infinite threads (even if it was synchronous, your `query.skip(skip)` would need to go inside the while loop not before it.

Try moving the query out to its own function, which is called recursively on success until you have read all of your objects. You should be able to adapt the code in this answer, which is for a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17268263/1176247

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I tried again http://pastebin.com/2X4ySksE but have a problem. The code enters the if but is unable to call the job again. The log shows - Result: Final Length 1000
I2014-05-01T19:31:12.018Z] in job
I2014-05-01T19:31:12.878Z] in query
I2014-05-01T19:31:12.878Z] in if